# Jquery/PHP script too heavy for browser: overcome browser limitations?

Tags: php, performance, browser

I've been working on a text comparison gizmo and it's proven ok until one of my texts was very very very long... Then I got this dreadful message from the browser: script too slow.
What does this mean? Is my browser buffer overflown? Are my computer / system resources exhausted?
Is there a way I can either compress / gzip / minify my script or overcome the browser limitations?
Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

Comment: The browser is complaining about only the JavaScript, which it runs, not the PHP.

Comment: PHP runs on a web server, not in the browser.  It's likely that the time complexity of your algorithm is too high.  There are ways to work around the "script too slow" error, but it's probably best if you correct the algorithm.  Can you give us more details as to how you're comparing texts?

Answer (score 2):

This message is generated, when script last too long, without passing control back to browser. It will this way block user interface. You should decompose your work into piecies, lasting not longer than a few seconds, and after each add next part to queue using **setTimeout**.  I've came across this problem in very heavy GWT-based application. Decomposing the work got rid of that message.

Answer (score 0):

Compressing the representation of the code won't fix the problem, which is that the JavaScript code uses too many resources (CPU/memory) when running. To fix this, move the heavy lifting to the server-side code instead of running it in the browser.